# Can we compare rigorously the computing time to evaluate ReLU or other nonlinear smooth activations?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

Can we say that, independently of the computer, computing relu and relu' is cheaper than computing f and f' for some other smooth non-linear activation (e.g. logistic, tanh)?

If not, what are the standard comparisons for common computers?

Are nice refs available?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: independently of the computer --> you cannot

Comment: There could be a theoretical/mathematical approach based on a model of digital calculus that could prove, for instance, that evaluating exp and relu is radically different

Comment: Well, the compute you are using can have dedicated hardware for specific operations. That’s the reason you can’t prove for any compute resource.

Comment: So you say there are common computers for which computing exp and relu take the same time?